# Yodlee Fastlink for removing a back accouny

Tags: yodlee

I have looked into the Yodlee fastlink integration where I can provide the users an option to add their bacnk accounts.

I'm wondering if there is an option to remove the bank accounts through the fastlink itself.?

Answer (score 1):

The FastLink floater can only be used for adding, editing or refreshing an account. You will have to make API calls for removing any account.